# Sorting a text file based on numerical values present in each line

Tags: linux, bash, sort

I have a text file containing paths of various wav files. But when they are created they are sorted based on alphabetical order. Hence the paths are like this

```
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_100.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_101.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_102.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_103.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_104.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_105.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_106.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_107.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_108.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_109.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_10.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_110.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_111.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_11.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_12.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_13.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_14.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_15.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_16.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_17.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_18.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_19.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_1.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_20.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_21.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_22.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_23.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_24.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_25.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_26.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_27.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_28.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_29.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_2.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_30.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_31.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_32.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_33.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_34.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_35.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_36.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_37.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_38.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_39.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_3.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_40.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_41.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_42.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_43.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_44.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_45.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_46.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_47.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_48.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_49.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_4.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_50.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_51.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_52.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_53.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_54.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_55.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_56.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_57.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_58.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_59.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_5.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_60.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_61.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_62.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_63.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_64.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_65.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_66.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_67.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_68.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_69.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_6.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_70.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_71.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_72.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_73.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_74.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_75.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_76.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_77.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_78.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_79.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_7.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_80.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_81.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_82.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_83.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_84.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_85.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_86.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_87.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_88.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_89.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_8.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_90.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_91.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_92.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_93.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_94.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_95.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_98.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_99.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_9.wav
```

I want them to be sorted based on the numerics after TC, so that they can be like this

```
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_1.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_2.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_3.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_4.wav
```

I have tried using `sort` and `sort -n` but none are working. Can anyone please help me with how to do this?

Comment: please update the question with your `sort` attempts

Comment: will all files have the same number of (sub)directories or could the number (of (sub)dirs) vary? if they could vary, please update to show an example; will all files have the same directory/filename prefix (eg, `/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_`) - if 'no' then please update to show some other samples

Comment: See `sort -V` with the GNU implementation of `sort`.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://askubuntu.com/q/1491272/158442

Comment: Turing: you're not *that* new. You know that posting the same question within 5 minutes on multiple sites is rude, because it wastes answerer's time. I'm a bit disappointed in you.

Answer (score 2):

If your file names are exactly as you show, you want to sort numericaly on the 5th field defined by `_`:

```
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_1.wav
_________ ______________ ___________ __ _____
1st field    2nd field    3d field   4th 5th
```

So, you can do:

```
$ sort -t _ -nk5,5 names 
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_1.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_2.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_3.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_4.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_5.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_6.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_7.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_8.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_9.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_10.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_11.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_12.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_13.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_14.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_15.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_16.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_17.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_18.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_19.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_20.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_21.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_22.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_23.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_24.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_25.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_26.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_27.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_28.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_29.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_30.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_31.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_32.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_33.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_34.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_35.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_36.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_37.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_38.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_39.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_40.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_41.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_42.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_43.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_44.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_45.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_46.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_47.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_48.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_49.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_50.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_51.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_52.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_53.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_54.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_55.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_56.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_57.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_58.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_59.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_60.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_61.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_62.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_63.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_64.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_65.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_66.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_67.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_68.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_69.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_70.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_71.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_72.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_73.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_74.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_75.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_76.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_77.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_78.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_79.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_80.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_81.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_82.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_83.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_84.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_85.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_86.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_87.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_88.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_89.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_90.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_91.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_92.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_93.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_94.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_95.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_98.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_99.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_100.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_101.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_102.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_103.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_104.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_105.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_106.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_107.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_108.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_109.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_110.wav
/home/wav_path/converted_Interpreter_TC_111.wav
```

That tells `sort` to use `_` as the field delimiter and to sort numerically (`-n`) on the 5th field only (`-k5,5`).

Or, if you have GNU `sort`, use `-V`:

```
       -V, --version-sort
              natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```

So you can do

```
sort -V names
```

and get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure for "I want to sort by a property of the file name" is:

1. decorate (i.e., put the key you want to use for sorting up front)
2. sort
3. de-decorate

If, and **only** if you know that these specific file names cannot contain new line characters: you can just decorate by matching the number with a regex, repeating it at the beginning of the line and then sorting numerically.

In this case, the chain looks like

```
<your_text_file \
    sed -n 's;^your_beginning_pattern\([[:digit:]]*\)your_end_pattern$;\1 &;p' | \
    sort -n | \
    sed 's;^[[:digit:]]* \(.*\)$;\1;'
```

You'll need to replace all that starts with `your_` with what is applicable to your use case. (That should be utterly doable in your trivial example. Give it a try!)

(The `sed -n … ;p'` ensures that only lines matching your pattern are printed. So, if you accidentally included files that did not match your pattern, they will be excluded. If you don't want that, don't use the `-n` sed option and the `p` flag.